# Make UArray a Functor

Tags: haskell

I want to treat `UArray` as instance of `Functor`. I want to write a numeric code, and I need to use something more efficient than `Array` to represent the state (says the profiler). I understand that I could write my code without using functors, but I think functors are a very valuable abstraction that I'd like to have.

As-is this doesn't work, because `UArray` is only an instance of `IArray` for certain basic types such as `Int` or `Double`. I am contemplating two approaches to make it work nonetheless:

- Return an error (either implicitly or explicitly) if the result of `fmap` is not an instance of `IArray`
- Define a "composite" type that is either based on `UArray` (if possible) or on `Array` (if not), akin to a C++ template specialization

I've tried various approaches based on various GHC extensions (existential types, functional dependencies, generalized algebraic data types, multi-parameter type classes, undecidable instances), but I just can't make things work. I always arrive at a point where I need to promise the compiler that "yes, the result will be representable via `UArray`", but there's just no syntax for it.

I've read various papers, tutorials, and documentation for the GHC extensions above in the hope to find an example that tells me how to do that. The closest I could find is https://wiki.haskell.org/GADTs_for_dummies, which defines a class `IsSimple` that is very close to what I probably need.

Can you give me a pointer for how to get started?

Comment: I'd try to use a restricted functor for this, similarly to restricted monads work. See e.g. http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/types.html#restricted-datatypes . Returning an error seems bad (typed programs should not go wrong -- not so easily, at least). The "composite" option may require sophisticated and fragile hackery like OverlappingInstances -- which I personally find too tricky to recommend.

Comment: If this is numeric code, you should consider whether **Hask** is even conceptually the right category. For linear algebra purposes, the `Functor` instance of `Array` doesn't really make _sense_, because it depends on a choice of what basis you use to describe your vector space. (Those mighty category-theory tools can still be handy to you, but perhaps better in [a completely different way](https://github.com/leftaroundabout/manifolds/blob/master/manifolds/Data/LinearMap/Category.hs).) — If all you want is a `map` function... then you really don't need a `Functor` instance!

Comment: Using chi's pointer, I implemented my own versions of Foldable and Functor that are independent of the Prelude's. This is working fine. And maybe this is indeed the way to go; as leftaroundabout says, I can use amap and azipWith. And yes, in the end I will want to define the notion of a vector space (and likely vector space transformers).

Answer (score 1):

[`Data.Vector.Unboxed`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.9.1/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html) provides an implementation of what I am looking for. It is already an instance of `Functor`, and automatically chooses an efficient representation if possible.